# Mysql how to select values from diffent columns into an single column amoung each other

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-columns

I got an table like this:

```
+------+-------+
|yearIn|yearOut|
+------+-------+
|1974  |2012   |
+------+-------+
|1935  |2020   |
+------+-------+
|1980  |1999   |
+------+-------+
```

I need to select all these years and have them in one column like this:

```
+------+
|years |
+------+
|1974  |
+------+
|1935  |
+------+
|1980  |
+------+
|2012  |
+------+
|2020  |
+------+
|1999  |
+------+
```

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT Years
FROM (
    SELECT yearIn AS Years FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT yearOut FROM yourTable
) y
ORDER BY Years;
```

**you also can use this without a subquery**

```
SELECT yearIn AS Years FROM yourTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT yearOut FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Years;
```

**EXPLAIN with and without subquery**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT Years
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT yearIn AS Years FROM yourTable
    ->     UNION ALL
    ->     SELECT yearOut FROM yourTable
    -> ) y
    -> ORDER BY Years;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | yourTable  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | NULL           |
|  3 | UNION       | yourTable  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | NULL           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> EXPLAIN     SELECT yearIn AS Years FROM yourTable
    ->     UNION ALL
    ->     SELECT yearOut FROM yourTable
    ->     ORDER BY Years;
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | yourTable  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  2 | UNION        | yourTable  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Why the subquery? Also, who said we want duplicates?

Comment: @shmosel - which duplicates ??

Comment: There aren't any in the example, but it could be a possibility.

Comment: the OP say **I need to select all these years**, so he will see ALL

Comment: I disagree with that interpretation, but there's no point in arguing over it. You still haven't explained the need for the subquery.

Comment: IMHO The requirement to remove the duplicates should be said explicitly. But the subquery isn't necessary.

Comment: @shmosel  - When you use it in a subquery, the Optimizer will not use a temporary table and then its faster. i have added the explains i my Answer.

Comment: @Bernd Buffen Well thank you very much, it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @BerndBuffen My EXPLAIN with a 1M-rows-table (MariaDB) doesn't contain `Using temporary` for both queries. The solution without a subquery is faster (4sec vs 7.5sec). Both columns are indexed. I guess the solution without subquery is sorting with O(n) because the engine knows that each subset is already ordered.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel  - Thats possible, the optimizer use statistical analyze of the data and can be different for many cases (index, rows, data in the fields, memory configuration,..) . so its no problem for me and i will also add the query without a subselect